# App crashes on RecyclerView (Adapter) on API 19

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying almost whole day, to fix this bug...but logcat doesn't provide enough info for me to understand what i am doing wrong. On my real device, running with API 23, my recyclerview is working well. As soon i run the app on emulator running API 19, my apps crashes, when it start loading adapter of recycleview. On emulator running Lollipop, these problem does not persist. Here is the code.

HistoryActivity

```
RecyclerView recyclerView1;
RecyclerView.Adapter rvadapter1;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager1;

public static ArrayList<String> itemAdress;
public static ArrayList<String> itemAuthor;
public static ArrayList<String> itemDate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rv);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.rv_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.title_recyclerview);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    itemAdress = new ArrayList<>();
    itemAuthor = new ArrayList<>();
    itemDate = new ArrayList<>();


    recyclerView1 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    rvLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager1);
    recyclerView1.setHasFixedSize(true);

    rvadapter1 = new RVAdapter();
    recyclerView1.setAdapter(rvadapter1);

}
```

RVAdapter

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ViewHolderKlasse> {

public class ViewHolderKlasse extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView itemAdress;
    TextView itemAuthor;
    TextView itemDate;

    public ViewHolderKlasse(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemAdress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemAdress);
        itemAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemAuthor);
        itemDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDate);

    }
}

 @Override
public ViewHolderKlasse onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {


    View itemView1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_rv, null);

    return new ViewHolderKlasse(itemView1);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderKlasse viewHolderKlasse, final int i) {

    viewHolderKlasse.itemAdress.setText(HistoryActivity.itemAdress.get(i));
    viewHolderKlasse.itemAuthor.setText(HistoryActivity.itemAuthor.get(i));
    viewHolderKlasse.itemDate.setText(HistoryActivity.itemDate.get(i));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return HistoryActivity.itemAdress.size();
}
}
```

And here is what i see in logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: support.plus.test, PID: 3640 java.lang.VerifyError:     support/plus/test/rv/RVAdapter at     support.plus.test.rv.HistoryActivity.onCreate(HistoryActivity.java:82)
```

Line 82 is:

```
        rvadapter1 = new RVAdapter();
```

Any help or ideas are welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your Adapter code? where you extends from Recyclerview.Adapter?

Comment: Which version of the compat library are you using?

Comment: @MeetTitan     'compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0''

Comment: @helldawg13 it is already mentioned in my question? Isn't it?

Comment: I think he means the RVAdapter code, that would be helpful

Comment: @holandaGo the second code snippet is the RVAdapter. I updated my question with the header, where it says RVAdapter.

Comment: are you using the default RecyclerView.Adapter without your own implementation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem, that was killing me...

When i add **only** this line to app build.gradle

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

app crashes on Android API 19 (KitKat).

After i added additionally this in the dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and this in Manifest

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

and sync project with gradle files, my app runs like a charm, and it stops crashing.

Thanks guys anyway!

Answer (score 2):

So, the VerifyError checks for 3 things:

- Branches point to valid locations.
- Data is initialized and references are type safe.
- Access to private, or package private, data and methods is controlled.

Also in your case, you're accessing the Activity from within the adapter which by itself is already an error in design, creates too much dependency. Create a constructor for your adapter with the info you need:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ViewHolderKlasse> {
    ArrayList<String> mItemAdress;
    ArrayList<String> mItemAuthor;
    ArrayList<String> mItemDate;
    public RVAdapter(ArrayList<String> itemAdress, ArrayList<String> itemAuthor, ArrayList<String> itemDate){
        mItemAdess = itemAdress;
        mItemAuthor = itemAuthor;
        mItemDate = itemDate;
    }
    ...
}
```

Use those arrays in your adapter and instead of creating the adapter through the empty constructor, create it through this new one.

Comment: still the same behavior, API 19 crashes, API 22, 23 working like a charm. I parse now the 3 arrayslist from my HistoryActivity to RVAdapter, and there i changed the usage of items, and i am not more getting them throw HistoryActivity.itemAdress. May it be some dependency on design or kind of it?...